# What does this syntax mean. (::*)

Tags: c++, c++11

While refactoring a piece of code I came across the line below:

```
class Bar
{
protected:
    int (Bar::* fooFunction)(float); //this line
}
```

I have never seen this kind of syntax before.  What is this syntax and why is it used it used in C++?

Comment: Pointer to member function. As to why it's used, that depends on what the class is supposed to do.

Comment: Lookup member function pointer in your favorite search engine. You can start at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a member function pointer.

Specifically, it's a pointer to a member function of a `Bar` object that takes a `float` argument and returns a `int`.

Read more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions

Answer (score -1):

> What is this syntax

It declares a pointer to member function.

> why is it used it used in C++?

It is used to point to non-static member functions.